# Recognizing the Serbian Alphabet in PHP GD

Tags: php, php-gd

I am trying to use some siberian alphabet name with PHP gd, but each time, I am getting error with ambigious letter. Below is my code :-

```
function properText($text){
        $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
        $text = preg_replace('~^(&([a-zA-Z0-9]);)~',htmlentities('${1}'),$text);
        return($text);
    }
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('testcreating.png');
    $returnedtext = properText('Jelena Jovanić');
    imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 90, 195, 0x000000, 'transcript.ttf', $returnedtext);
    imagealphablending($im, true);
    imagesavealpha($im, true);
    imageJpeg($im, "testcreating.jpg", 85);
    imagedestroy($im);
    return HTML::image('testcreating.jpg');
```

But it is not able to recognise letter `ć`, it is giving ambigous code.

How can i resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: does the font your using have the required characters?

Comment: OMG ! I don't think so. Can you recommend some font , which can support siberian font ?

Comment: sorry a little out side my area, but google suggests: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/serbian

Comment: Kindly mention this as answer, so that i can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font you're using "transcript.ttf" must support the alphabet you want to use.

I can't vouch for any of theses but i found a site that claims theses fonts will support the Siberian alphabet: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/serbian